# Why webpack incorrectly resolve a local path to Javascript file as root path?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using webpack 4.20.0 npm package. One of the dependencies of my dependencies in the npm package `mimer`. `mimer` has a file `mime.types` located in `node_modules/mimer/lib/data/mime.types`. The package also has a file `node_modules/mimer/lib/exec.js` which contains the following line:

```
list: (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.cwd) ? require('./data/parser')(__dirname + '/data/mime.types') : $_MIMER_DATA_LIST
```

webpack succeeds to compile my code and I get a bundle but when I run the bundle with node.js I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//data/mime.types'
```

I think it occurs as a result of webpack incorrectly providing `__dirname` value by resolving `__dirname` as root. Is there a way to solve such an issue in webpack?

This is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')


module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
    path: path.resolve(__dirname)
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^(hiredis|transifex)$/)
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            rootMode: 'upward'
          }
        },
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check with `node: { __dirname: true }` ? add it to the webpack.config file.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty this worked thanks!

Comment: Cool let me post it as a answer for whoever stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically webpack returns `__dirname` to be `/`. So you basically have to tell webpack to resolve `__dirname`.

add:

```
node: {
    __dirname: true
}
```

same thing with `__filename` as well.